# Unwanted whitespace when echoing output in php

Tags: php, html, printing, whitespace, stdout

I am currently trying to write a program that outputs the stdout output of a c program to a text area in html (using php).

This is what I have thus far:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec("./hello");
?>
<textarea name="view" cols="80" rows="24" readonly>
    <?php echo $output; ?>
</textarea>
```

This prints the correct output, but it adds 2 tabs ahaed of the first character, so instead of

```
Hello World!
```

It prints

```
        Hello World!
```

This is my first time using either php or html, so I'm sure it's something fairly easy to fix. I just can't seem to find anything addressing this specifically online, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

(Just in case it's not obvious the c program is just a simple hello world, that prints fine on the terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that is out of the php tags are echoed "as-is". Consequently, you echoed two tabs in front of your `<?php echo $output; ?>` within the textarea.

try this :

```
<textarea name="view" cols="80" rows="24" readonly><?php echo $output; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your whitespaces inside the `<textarea>` tags:

```
<textarea name="view" cols="80" rows="24" readonly>
    <?php echo $output; ?>
</textarea>
```

The text between your tags will be taken as the textareas value.

So your value will be 4 whitespaces and then the output of your echo statement.

**tl;dr**: Remove your indent (4 spaces):

```
<textarea name="view" cols="80" rows="24" readonly>
<?php echo $output; ?>
</textarea>
```